# Adding Different sublayers to UITableViewCell Covering subviews of Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As I'm bounding the section of `UITableViewCell` like this...

With this Code...

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    //Border Across 1st Section
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        CGFloat cornerRadius = 3.f;
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        self.layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
        BOOL addLine = NO;
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
        } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
            addLine = YES;
        } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        } else {
            CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
            addLine = YES;
        }
        self.layer.path = pathRef;
        CFRelease(pathRef);
        //set the border color
        self.layer.strokeColor = UNDERLINE_COLOR_NEXT.CGColor;
        //set the border width
        self.layer.lineWidth = 1;
        self.layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

        if (addLine == YES) {
            CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
            CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
            lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width, lineHeight);
            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
            [self.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
        }

        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        [testView.layer insertSublayer:self.layer atIndex:0];
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        cell.backgroundView = testView;
    }
}
}
```

And in Tableview's delegate method I'm adding sublayer to `CAShapeLayer` for each cell...like this...

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.view endEditing:YES];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    UITableViewCell *lCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath];
    CALayer *lLayer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
    lLayer.frame = CGRectInset(lCell.bounds,10,0);
    lLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.f].CGColor;
    [lCell.layer addSublayer:lLayer]; //Last indexPath white

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CALayer *cLayer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
    cLayer.frame = CGRectInset(cell.bounds,10,0);
    cLayer.backgroundColor = navBarColor.CGColor;
    [cell.layer addSublayer:cLayer]; //Current Index Yellow

    self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

}
```

But when i'm tapping on any cell, layer is covering subview of cell Were i'm wrong please set my direction

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want to be a yellow color in your selected indexpath right?

Comment: YES absolutely right

Comment: your current  problem is if you tap on indexpath 0 and yellow color will display on indexpath 3 right?

Comment: YES right If I tap on any cell layer is showing up in last cell

Comment: have you try my answer?

Comment: check my updated answer which is in swift but you can convert in objective c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is may be with this line `[self.layer addSublayer:cLayer];` you need to add layer in cell. It should be like.

```
[cell.layer addSublayer:cLayer];
```

You need to set `[cell.layer addSublayer:cLayer];` for both current and previous selection.

**Edit:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIView *selectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    selectedView.backgroundColor = navBarColor.CGColor;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
}
```

Now remove code inside `didSelect` where you are setting color and removing it.

Comment: Thanks Nirav this solution worked but the layer is covering subviews of cell

Comment: I dont understand..??

Comment: @MohammedHussain Are you using custom TableCell?

Comment: No im not using custom

Comment: Thanks Nirav I got the solution in jignesh answer but you too made a great effort thanks

Comment: @MohammedHussain Please check once edited answer :), it will reduce your whole code with just 4 lines, don't forgot to remove code from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` now there is no necessary of it.

Comment: @MohammedHussain Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

first your cell background view, give tag to identify that like this way

must add this line

```
 testView.tag = 9999;
```

it's look like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
  [testView.layer insertSublayer:self.layer atIndex:0];
  testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
  testView.tag = 9999;
  cell.backgroundView = testView;

}
```

now implement  didSelectRow method is like this way

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.view endEditing:YES];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    UITableViewCell *lCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath];
    UIView *bgView = [[lCell backgroundView] viewWithTag:9999]
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)bgView.layer.sublayers[0];
    layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.f].CGColor //Last indexPath white


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *bgView = [[cell backgroundView] viewWithTag:9999]
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)bgView.layer.sublayers[0];
    layer.fillColor = navBarColor.CGColor  //Current Index Yellow


    self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jignesh this solution worked but the layer is covering subviews of cell

Comment: No yellow color is not showing up...- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
       
        [lCell.layer insertSublayer:lLayer atIndex:0]; //Last indexPath white

        [cell.layer insertSublayer:cLayer atIndex:0]; //Current Index Yellow
        }

Comment: Thanks jignesh it is great help..Thanks for all your effort you are the winner it worked...

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is change the color of the currently selected cell there is a far more simple solution. What you can do is set the highlighted state of all your `UITableViewCell` to be a separate `UIView`. Simply click the outlet present in the cell and drag and drop the connection from the `UITableViewCell` to `UIView` (Check the screenshot for the outlet to drag from). This will set the selected the cell to take on the view that you set it to and hence change the background color leaving all the elements inside the cell unchanged. This way you won't have to handle any color changes etc that may come up owing to cell re-use

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.view endEditing:YES];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

UITableViewCell *lCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath];
UIView *bgView = [[lCell backgroundView] viewWithTag:9999]
CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)bgView.layer.sublayers[0];
layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.f].CGColor //Last indexPath white


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *bgView = [[cell backgroundView] viewWithTag:9999]
CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)bgView.layer.sublayers[0];
layer.fillColor = navBarColor.CGColor  //Current Index Yellow


self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

 }
}
```